# Robotium on testdroid

Tags: robotium, testdroid

I am a newbie in android testing. When I run a robotium test case on testdroid it is giving me view not found error on some devices.It is really annoying. Any help?

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: RecyclerView is not found!
at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:50)
at com.robotium.solo.Clicker.clickInRecyclerView(Clicker.java:570)
at com.robotium.solo.Solo.clickInRecyclerView(Solo.java:1788)
```

Comment: Please provide an error and stacktrace. Adding any code can help in determining your problem.

Comment: @ImAtWar ...please check once

Comment: is seems to be that Robotium is unable to find RecyclerView. Please put your test class, xml and if possible class code - the two first are obligatory